# Sign SAML AuthNRequest in JMeter

Tags: xml, groovy, jmeter, saml, sign

I try to sign plain `XML` content with private key of SP and `X.509` public certificate of the IdP to use in authentication process for load testing in `JMeter`. I found onelogin's Java SAML toolkit, but not sure how to import in a `Groovy` script. I just tried to build reproduce functionality of this webapp: https://www.samltool.com/sign_authn.php

Answer (score -3):

You can use not only `Groovy`, but also `Java`:

1. Add the [BeanShell Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) or [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (and choose `Java BeanShell` in it's `Language` combobox) to Test Plan.
2. Try to use [OneLogin's SAML Java Toolkit](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml)
3. Paste your Java code to BeanShell Script box.

For full details on using `BeanShell`, please see:

- [JMeter with BeanShell Guide](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/06/testing-complex-logic-with-jmeter-beanshell/)
- [BeanShell website](http://www.beanshell.org/)

Comment: I see, but could you please give some more specific answer.

Comment: Have you try to use OneLogin's SAML Java Toolkit?

Comment: Sure, but I have problem with JMeter integration of this toolkit.

Comment: What exactly problem? Any errors while integration?

Comment: Toolkit should be added as a project to IDE, but can't see how it works in Groovy script.

Comment: I gave you award, but still unsure, how to use it in Groovy script.